# Google sheers: On edit event trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, editing

I have a dropdown (data validation) cell and I need to clear a few cells every time that the user changes that drop down. I am using the script below and nothing happens.

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (e) {
     var ss = e.source;
     var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var editedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
     var tsheet = "Target";
     if(sname === tsheet && editedCell.getColumn() == 3 && editedCell.getrow() == 5){   
         value = "";
         ss.s.getRange(7,3).setValue(value);
         ss.s.getRange(9,3).setValue(value);
         ss.s.getRange(10,3).setValue(value);
         ss.s.getRange(12,3).setValue(value);
         ss.s.getRange(14,3).setValue(value);
         ss.s.getRange(16,3).setValue(value);      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: var sname = s.getSheetName(); missing. After var s & before if

Comment: Also getrow() should be getRow().

Answer (score 0):

You have `sname === tsheet`. I imagine you just want the `==` operator or if you're just declaring a new variable, just use a regular assignment outside the if. You never use sname, so I don't quite see what it's for. Also, rather than setting the cells to an empty value, you can use [clear()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear()) instead. If the issue still persists, check that your triggers are properly set up in your script (Resources -> Current Project's Triggers).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative version:

```
function onEdit(e){
 var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
 if(s.getName() !== "Target" || e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'C5') return;   
 [7, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16].map(function (r) {
 s.getRange("C"+r).clear();
     });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. 

I get an error:

TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 9, file "Code")Dismiss

Comment: cannot be run from the script editor as there is no event. you must run by actually editing a cell.

Comment: Could not have said it any better.. thanks for jumping in @ScampMichael :-)